# htaccess mod rewrite with optional slash

Tags: .htaccess

We're switching from an old site to a new site with better URLs for SEO.
I'm trying to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/boots/materialid/(.*)/colour/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/boots/$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However the problem is:

1) Instead of using `(.*)`, can I specify that this can have the following characters

- any alphanumeric character `a-zA-Z0-9`
- any Euro character such as German special UTF8 characters
- `_` and `-` symbols
- also can contain a `+` symbol (e.g. black+leather)

2) If the above won't work, and for my general knowledge on this, how do I update the above so that a trailing slash is optional? E.g. for the above rule, going to

```
www.mydomain.com/materialid/leather/colour/blue/
```

sends me to

```
www.mydomain.com/blue//leather
```

The extra slash comes because of the slash after "blue" in the original URL, but I need to exclude this.

Comment: Making a character optional in Regex is achieved by appending a `?` to it. So `www.url.com/material/leather/colour/blue/?`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please see my comment below as well - can I also add an optional /index.php? e.g. www.url.com/material/leather/colour/blue/?(index.php)? ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/boots/materialid/([^/]*)/colour/([^/]*)/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/boots/$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`[^/]` matches any character that is NOT a slash.  `/?` means an optional trailing slash (note that it is outside of the capturing parentheses, so that it will not be included in the rewritten URL).

**EDIT**

As per your comment, to add an optional /index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^products/boots/materialid/([^/]*)/colour/([^/]*)(/|/index\.php)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/boots/$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. Great :) could you also let me know how to add an optional "/index.php" exactly to the code you mentioned above? While the traling slash /? is optional, there is also a chance that the URL may be accessed like this ..../index.php - therefore I want the same rule applied. Is it possible?

Comment: @rishijd Yes, you can have an optional `index.php` on the end as well. However, you want to avoid `blueindex.php` being redirected, so you need some slightly fancy regex: `.../blue(/(index\.php)?)?`. Note the escaped `.`.